# How do you restrict contributors from Pushing to a private repository without a Fork?

Tags: github

Is there a way for me to invite a contributor, allow him to **fork** from my project and submit a **Pull Request**, **without** being able to **commit** and **Push** directly into the repository ?

I am new to this, I'm doing some testing and it seems that it should be an easy way to accomplish this, but I cannot find it. I have two accounts and it seems that I can just delete and modify anything in the repository, from the collaborator (guest) account, with no restrictions and moderation from the owner account.

Comment: Private repos generally use a branching model rather than a fork-then-branch model. Set up protected branches that block force pushes, require PR checks, and have required reviews.

Comment: Ok so what I need to do is set up a protected branch ? I just don't want any contributors to be able to push changes without my approval.